# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/HttpMessage.class

Tags: android, android-multidex

I'm getting the following error. I have not tried to solve it the last two days, but nothing had solved the problem.
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.

> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/HttpMessage.class
>       here is my build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mycompany.newlogin"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {

}
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
```

}

please help me with this .thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at your referenced packages, org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client seems to contain at least some classes of httpcore, especially that one mentioned in your error message. So I guess you simply can't and shouldn't use both as dependencies, but only the ones you really need.

Answer (score 5):

I too had this Error and i resolved this by removing `httpcore`

in your `build.gradle(app)` Remove these lines

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
```

and then add latest apache library to your `build.gradle(app)`

```
  compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
```

Comment: You grace buddy. Happy Diwali

Answer (score 0):

The following libraries were causing conflict and i removed it from build.gradle

```
  compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
  compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
```

and i left only with :

```
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
```